# How to change the color from selected option in selectbox with jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a select with several options and one of them is `Offside`. This one should be colored red. When Offside is selected, it should be colored red, and that works fine.

But when i change the selected to, per example `Apple`, Apple should be colored black as selected. And when Apple is selected and i choose option Offside, it should be colored red. I do not succeed in that.

```js
$('.blog-category:contains(Offside)').addClass('text-red'); // make Offside in options red

$('.categories option:selected:contains(Offside)').closest('select').addClass('text-red');
//$('.categories option:selected:not(contains(Offside)').closest('select').addClass('text-black');
```

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}

.text-black {
  color: black;
}

select option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="categories">
  <option class="blog-category" value="Offside" selected>Offside</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Peach">Peach</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Orange">Orange</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Offside">Offside</option>
</select>

<select class="categories">
  <option class="blog-category" value="Apple" selected>Apple</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Peach">Peach</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Orange">Orange</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Offside">Offside</option>
</select>
```

Hers is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hfL3cw58/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you need to toggle the `text-red` class on the select based on whether the `Offside` option was selected. You can do this by attaching a `change` event handler and toggling the class as required. Try this:

```js
$('select option:contains("Offside")').css('color', 'red');

$('.categories').on('change', e => {
  $(e.target).toggleClass('text-red', e.target.value === 'Offside')
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}

.text-black {
  color: black;
}

select option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="categories">
  <option class="blog-category" value="Offside" selected>Offside</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Apple">Apple</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Peach">Peach</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Orange">Orange</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Offside">Offside</option>
</select>

<select class="categories">
  <option class="blog-category" value="Apple" selected>Apple</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Peach">Peach</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Orange">Orange</option>
  <option class="blog-category" value="Offside">Offside</option>
</select>
```

One thing to note here is that changing the CSS properties of `option` elements is not well supported across browsers. If you need this to work reliably I would suggest using a third party select library which allows you full control of the UI, such as [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [Select2](https://select2.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your JS is that you add a class but you are not removing it when not required because of which you are not able to get the desired results. Try this in your JS, it will work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".categories").each(selectColorChange);
});
$('.categories').on("change",selectColorChange);
function selectColorChange(){
    var x = $(this).find("option:selected").val()
  if(x=="Offside"){
    $(this).addClass("text-red");
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass("text-red");
  }
}
```

I have made edits to your fiddle. Check out on: https://jsfiddle.net/9paLnzhc/